# How do I redirect to the remote URL through jsp without changing the previous URL in address bar?

Tags: jsp

I want to redirect to the remote URL through JSP without updating the previous URL in address bar. I have tried response.sendRedirect(URLtobeOpened) and request.getRequestDispatcher(URLtobeOpened).forward(request,response) but the **problem** is that-

**1. sendRedirect()** will be redirecting to the remote URL and changes the URL in the address bar (which I dont want to update).

**2.getRequestDispatcher()** is referring to the local resource only, I am not able to open remote URL through this method.

How do I resolve this problem. Suggest me some solution in JSP.

Comment: If your intention is to use some third party services only by remote url, you can use ajax call.